Does Blender evaluate fields iteratively?
I'm building a node tree that uses a Set Position node on curve points. Position, evaluated on the previous curve point on the spline, is used in the calculation.

Because I expected Blender to iterate on curve points starting from the curve root, I also expected each evaluation of Position to yield a previous output of the expression; so when reading point 0's Position to calculate point 1's Position, it would have already been modified by Set Position in the previous iteration.
From troubleshooting my node tree, it seems my expectation was wrong, so the Position input will always yield the point's original Position before the Set Position evaluation.
I'm looking for clarification on how exactly Blender handles this case. I also don't know how to best achieve the behavior I expected.

Whatever values you read, you're reading from the previous state of the geometry, which is the state before the currently evaluated node (here: "Set Position") was run. This allows geonodes to be fast, because calculation can be parallelized, but it also forces you to use repeat zones if you want to modify the iterator, for example: Need help with creating space between books (Geometry Nodes) or Access previous field value using "Accumulate Field" node

Got it. I was weary of using a repeat zone if it could be avoided. I'm studying those examples. Thanks for the references.
